# How to create radio/static interference?

Tags: sound-effects, film-sound-design

I have a scene with dialogue coming over a radio/telcom speaker... I want to introduce the sound effect of radio interference and static cutting in and out...

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worldizing is probably your best bet. transmit the audio through some hand-held CB's and record the output. Also, the type of sound will depend on the 'fake' modulation - FM will sound different from AM, SSB etc.